# Set special from date and special to date in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want set special from date and special to date in Magento 2, i tryed this code but it not work. please help me.

```
foreach ($collection as $products) {
        $_product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($products->getProductId());
        $_product->setSpecialFromDate(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($products->getStartDate())));
        $_product->setSpecialToDate(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($products->getEndDate())));
        $_product->save();
    }
```

$products->getStartDate() = string(19) "2019-10-20 00:00:00"

$products->getEndDate() = string(19) "2019-10-20 00:00:00"

Comment: Check https://blog.mdnsolutions.com/magento-2-set-price-and-special-price-per-store-programmatically/

Comment: yes, but it also not work for me

Comment: Is $products->getStartDate() = string(19) "2019-10-20 00:00:00" is saving with your product's special from date?

Comment: no, it not save